# How to capture alert screenshot in Selenium WebDriver 4.7.2, Java 17

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, takesscreenshot

Selenium tests unable to capture screenshot when alert is raised.

I set the desired capability too.

```
chromeOptions.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNHANDLED_PROMPT_BEHAVIOUR, "ignore");
```

But the script failing at 2nd line. Tried applying explicit waits too but no use.

```
driverManager.getWebDriver().switchTo().alert();
byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driverManager.getWebDriver()).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
scenario.attach(screenshot, "image/png", "attachment-"+LocalTime.now().toSecondOfDay());
driverManager.getWebDriver().switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Other stack overflow articles doesn't seem to help. Is there any solution for this? Are there any popular 3rd party libraries can be used for this purpose?

Comment: try/catch that line and include the exception in your post.  For the unhandled prompt behavior you should use the constant... and also options.  Ex: options.setUnhandledPromptBehaviour(UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.IGNORE);  https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/index.html?org/openqa/selenium/UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.html